# My mac keeps changing its name to "enterprise (2)". How do I keep it as enterprise?

Tags: macos

I want my mac to be named enterprise, but for some reason that escapes me, lately, it gets automatically renamed to "enterprise (2)":

[image]

Any ideas how I make it stick as enterprise?

Comment: It was named enterprise before and there are no other machines named enterprise on this network.

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153080/computer-name-keeps-changing-osx-10-10-14a389

It seems to be a bug that's been there for some time.

Comment: @elofturtle thanks, I found the right answer there.

Answer (score 2):

From [a similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153080/computer-name-keeps-changing-osx-10-10-14a389) with many answers on “Ask Different,” I found [this is the one that worked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/161487). This is what it says:

To be able to achieve this, run the following commands on the terminal:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :ProgramArguments: string --no-namechange" /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist

sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist

sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
```

and

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName <host-name-U-want>
sudo scutil --set HostName <host-name-U-want>
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName <host-name-U-want>
hostname -f
```